# How to make JS be called only once for all pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `header.html` page that I keep loading dynamically with JavaScript into all my webpages via `add_header.js`.

The `header.html` includes a notification badge that shows a red span with the number of the notifications.

In my `add_header.js` I have a JS function that removes the red span when the badge is clicked.

Everything works great for one page, but when I go to an other page, the `header.html` gets loaded again so the notification is red again.

How can I fix this, in order for the function to be executed only one time for all pages?

webpage.html

```
<script src="js/add_header.js"></script>
 <div id="header">
</div>
```

my header.html

```
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
  <li class="nav-item d-md-down-none">
    <a id="notif-link" class="nav-link" href="#" title="Notifications">
     <span id="notif" class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color:red;"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

my add_header.js

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 var list_notif=["Notification1","Notification2","Notification3","Notification4"];
 var number_notif=list_notif.length;
 $('#notif').text(number_notif);

 $('#notif-link').focus(
    function(){
      $('#notif').remove(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You could use local storage to store the state of a badge.

Comment: Or let know header.html that the badge was clicked so it doesn't show it again. How exactly is your HTML generated?

Comment: I want to post this as comments but dont have enoughr repo to do it there so posting at as answer. Can you please post code which you hare using in both files? Moreover make sure that you are saving some values which shows that a message has been read or not? something is "is_read" *true* *false* may work for you. So before showing red span will need to check for that read status.

Comment: @alexmac I didn't understand, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Yep, the problem is that you are using hardcoded html... You either need to store a cookie/localStorage value to remove the html node, or do the oposite, have it not shown and only display it when needed.

Comment: @Salketer could you please elaborate more? or post an answer?

Comment: No. You need to describe where the notifications are coming from in the first place. There is absolutely no code being able to keep state. What happens when a new notification comes in? etc...